# Are there English proverbs that warn against “speaking up” in front of people?

Tags: proverbs

I recall a Japanese proverb, “犬も歩けば棒に当たる,” of which literal translation is “When a dog rambles around outside, he get a hit with a neighbor’s stick,” meaning, “Don’t come on the surface, don’t try to do anything new, don't say anything, otherwise you’ll be criticized, blamed, or get hurt.”

We have the similar expression, 物言えば唇寒し秋の風　in 和歌 – Japanese classic poem, which can be translated as “In autumn, you feel cold on your lips anytime you utter a word, “ which admonishes you not venture to speak up in public, just be reticent.

It’s understandable that we have a lot of such proverbs and maxims teaching the merit of keeping silent after going through the ages of a tight feudalistic social regime and being severely educated on Confucius doctrines which values silence, and action more than speech, but I wonder if there is the similar saying to “dog and autumn wind” analogies in Anglo-American world where the freedom of speech and the power of eloquence have been highly valued.

I know you have the saying, “Speech is silver but silence is golden” or just "Silence is golden." Are there any other proverbs or set phrases than “Silence is golden.” to admonish you not to speak up, or being self-assertive?

P.S. The **focus** of my question is "**the restraint / gagging of free speech**"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the word for a group holding back one of its members trying to rise above the group?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240027/what-is-the-word-for-a-group-holding-back-one-of-its-members-trying-to-rise-abov)

Comment: [Are there counterpart English expressions to Japanese proverb, "the nail that pops up is always hammered down?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119705/are-there-counterpart-english-expressions-to-japanese-proverb-the-nail-that-po)

Comment: @Mazura.Dan Bron gave "The nail which sticks up gets pownded down, " which is very close to Japanese one and said it's originated in the East.

Comment: I wonder if there is a proverb that talks about a person who receives a significant amount of consensus and praise, awards and acclaims but tends to focus their attention on a  single negative episode or criticism.

Comment: ＠Ｍari-Lou. I roughly and wrongly memorized "No question .." mentioned by Medica.  Anyway  I think this line is very close to my favorite Japanese saying - Asking a question is a momentary shame. Not asking question is a lifetime shame. I buy this English version as the most favorite remedy for the frustration for getting a down /close vote. whichever it is reasonable or unreasonable.

Comment: Hey @YoichiOishi i think you may have used slightly the wrong phrase with "gagging of free speech" ... that phrase 'free speech' tends to imply "political" speech don't you think?  I feel the essence of what you are asking is more the situation where - oh - say in office politics, it's often better to just shut up!  (there's no "political" aspect there.)

Comment: The first proverb in the question doesn't sound much like it has to do with speaking up. It bears more similarity with the English: _"Curiosity killed the cat."_

Comment: I'm afraid I think you've misunderstood your first proverb. It roughly translates as 'even an idiot gets lucky sometimes'

Comment: Just to be clear, if you hadn't excluded it, the very well known "silence is golden" would be the right answer?

Comment: There is a whole constellation of stuff developed around the idea of a (malfuntioning) "brain mouth filter".

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are many such idioms, not so many proverbs that I can think of.

Maybe the most famous proverb on keeping silent is from [Proverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Proverbs) 17:28:

> Even a fool, when he holds his peace, is counted wise: and he that shuts his lips is esteemed a man of understanding.

It's repeated in various parts of Scripture in different phrasing. I think it's the basis of the familiar

> It is better to be silent and be thought a fool, than to speak and remove all doubt.

The following is attributed to Confucius:

> Silence is a true friend who never betrays.

In addition to the idioms @Dan Bron mentions, there is also **flying under the radar**, originally meaning avoiding detection, but now meaning avoiding negative attention as well.

However, even wise people often embrace silence, and there is a saying in teaching that no question is a stupid question. How can one learn if one doesn't ask questions?

Comment: Oh, I really like the second idiom "... speak and remove all doubt".  Also "flying under the radar". You should bold or otherwise emphasize that. +1.

Comment: These do refer more to the possibility of looking stupid, not necessarily being punished for criticism. OP's proverbs are much stronger.

Comment: I've liked the modern spin off of "a rolling stone gathers no moss": "A closed mouth gathers no foot."  (I don't post this as an answer because it's the same sentiment as this answer, and I don't think it (or this answer) captures the social pressures mentioned in the question (even if it's been accepted): 'P.S. The focus of my question is "the restraint / gagging of free speech"'.  These sayings are more about self-restraint rather than externally imposed silence.

Comment: The one from my high school days was "It's better to be thought a fool than to open your mouth and remove all doubt."

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes, that one as well. It does go to show that this kind of sentiment is well known. To Joshua Taylor - That one is new to me; I like it!

Comment: I would second the comment of @Chieron . These phrases are intended to enhance your humility rather than to protect you from the consequences of speaking out, therefore I do not regard this as a correct answer

Comment: I like "No question is a stupid question" in regard with my question. It reminds me  Abraham Lincoln's wise saying, "The man who can't make mistakes, can't make anything," that was given by JR in my question asking the meaning of Lincoln's word, "Let'en up easy" in July three years ago.

Comment: @YoichiOishi - JR has a lot of good things to say. If you want more sayings along the lines of "No question is a stupid question" (often also stated as, "There's no such thing as a stupid question"), that would be an interesting question (no pun intended!)

Answer (score 78):

We [stole the proverb](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Japanese_proverbs#%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B%E6%9D%AD%E3%81%AF%E6%89%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B) from you guys¹:

> #### The nail which sticks up gets pounded down.

Unlike the [squeaky wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_squeaky_wheel_gets_the_grease), of course, which gets the grease.

That the former proverb originated in the East and the latter in the West is sometimes held up as an exemplar of the cultural differences.

But, in contradiction to Kipling's famous observation that [never the twain shall meet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_East_and_West),  an indigenous Western expression, courtesy of [the Bard himself](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/discretion.html)  is:

> #### Discretion is the better part of valor.

But, unlike the nail proverb, this one focuses more on the positive outcomes of keeping mum, rather than the negative consequences.

And one which is indigenous, and focuses on the negative outcomes, but is still offered as friendly advice, not a reprimand, is:

> #### Keep your head down.

And slightly more of a reprimand:

> #### Don't make waves!

or, in a similar nautical theme:

> #### Don't rock the boat!

I suppose it is not so surprising that the West has passed through some bloody and tyrannical ages itself. Apparently when everyone was [on boats](http://youtu.be/R7yfISlGLNU).

¹  <sub>"[English] don't just borrow words; on occasion, English has pursued other languages down alleyways to beat them unconscious and rifle their pockets for new vocabulary." -- James Nicoll, [rec.arts.sf-lovers, 1990-May-30](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/James_Nicoll#1990s)</sub>

Comment: PS: All the puns were occidental. I promise.

Comment: "Don't rock the boat" would probably be the most common of these expressions that I encounter in Australia as a native English speaker..

Comment: @AaronLavers Well, you guys have a lot of boats....

Comment: haha, yes, but apparently we stopped them.

Probably outside of the environment.

Comment: It's been a while since I was here... but why am I not surprised that yours is the topvoted answer!! When I read the question title, I thought of the Lincoln(?) quote: "Better to remain silent and be thought a fool than to speak and remove all doubt". But that probably doesn't apply here.

Comment: Ah, @TusharRaj, good to see you! We'd (I'd) missed you! If you go upvote medica's suggestion of "better to remain silent and remove all doubt", then perhaps mine wouldn't be the topvoted answer any longer ;) And do stick around for a while.

Comment: @DanBron: Gladly. I missed you (guys) too!

Comment: There's also "tall poppy syndrome" -related phrases.

Comment: @JoeBlow That would make a good answer. You should add it. Tomorrow, when I get more votes to spend, you're guaranteed my upvote.

Comment: Although you've missed the Prohibition-era pun - "the squeaky wheel gets greased".  (For non-English speakers, "greased" is early-20th-century American slang for "killed", perhaps from submachine guns being known as "grease guns".)  That changes the meaning of the phrase back to the "tall poppy/nail" meaning, with an added joke included.

Comment: Amusing anecdote: there used to be a website that would take a sentence in English and automatically apply Google Translate to it several times over until finally bringing it back to English. One notable humorous example: "Don't rock the boat" became "do not balance the boat."

Comment: My fourth-grade teacher used to use the "squeaky wheel", usually just before handing out "lines".

Comment: "[The nail that sticks out shall be hammered down](https://www.quora.com/What-do-you-think-about-the-Japanese-proverb-The-nail-that-sticks-out-shall-be-hammered-down?share=1)" is the form I am familiar with. Heard it many times.

Comment: The Shakespeare (mis)quote is not about keeping quiet, it is about being cautious rather than rashly brave. It was spoken by Falstaff and was meant to be ironic. Granted, it has been misused so much that it can be said to mean a number of different things in common usage.

Answer (score 11):

**"Whatever You Say, Say Nothing"**

This is the title of a [poem](http://www.blueridgejournal.com/poems/sh-what.htm) by Irish poet Seamus Heaney. The phrase itself is from a time and place where it was necessary to *keep your head down*.

Here's a snippet:

> [...]
> Where to be saved you only must save face
> And **whatever you say, you say nothing.**
>
> Smoke-signals are loud-mouthed compared with us:
> Manoeuvrings to find out name and school,
> Subtle discrimination by addresses
> With hardly an exception to the rule
>
> That Norman, Ken and Sidney signalled Prod
> And Seamus (call me Sean) was sure-fire Pape.
> O land of password, handgrip, wink and nod,
> Of open minds as open as a trap,

Quoting from [fawbie.com](http://fawbie.com/2012/10/14/whatever-you-say-say-nothing/):

> A poster put up during the ‘Troubles’, featuring a masked, uniformed paramilitary carrying a sten gun, bore the legend: *Loose-talk costs lives In taxis On the phone In clubs and bars At football matches At home with friends Anywhere Whatever you say – say nothing*. Composed of amateurish cut and pasted newspaper headings and snippets it was evidently the work of extremist factions. It was threatening.
>
> A society is warned to refrain from unguarded political or religious comments that could cause a violent reaction. Heaney levels his anger against propagandist threats to free speech at a time when the voices of the neutral majority should be raised in protest; equally he deplores the imposition of repressive ‘political’ measures that fly in the face of natural justice. He acknowledges that he himself may not be practising what he preaches.

Comment: I love literary answers.  And this one is new to me.  Awesome. In the US the corresponding term is "Loose Lips Sink Ships". Was widely deployed during WWII.

Comment: @DanBron Yes, the poster's a pretty clear reference to that and to "Careless talk costs lives", another WWII admonition.

Comment: Also a song based on this! Clancy and Makem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vm51sR4tRY
*Whatever You Say Say Nothing*

Comment: @Dan I just watched & enjoyed the song. I read up now that original song released 1981 by Colum Sands according to http://www.columsands.com/biography.html Hard to know if it was influenced by the 1975 poem or if that idiom was already well known in N. Ireland - perhaps both!

Answer (score 8):

Not *exactly* what you ask for, but the first thing that came to mind was

### Speech is silver, silence is golden

This is sometimes shortened to just *silence is golden*, as in the (famous?) [Tremeloes song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n03g8nsaBro).

Comment: OP updated question to include this.

Comment: Hahaha, I had heard that awful, awful song but had not realized it was the Tremeloes, a band I only knew of from the well-known story about how they got their recording contract in the face of [very strong competition](https://blueapsara.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/the-end-of-publishing/).

Answer (score 6):

Two more:

- You are a master of an unspoken word, and a slave of a spoken one.

Direct translation from Russian:

- A word is not a sparrow - you can not catch it when it escapes.

Comment: I've seen your first one [in this version](http://www.aish.com/sp/dl/46120172.html): "Before you speak, you are the master of your words. After you speak, your words become your master."

Answer (score 5):

### **The tallest blade of grass is the first to be cut...**

While not directly related to speech, this saying means that if you stand out too much you will be the target of negative attention.

[image: grass]

Photo credit to [Despair, Inc.](http://despair.com/)

Comment: A popular Australian version of this is “Tall poppies get cut down” (and variations).

Answer (score 4):

**Children should be seen and not heard** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Children+should+be+seen+and+not+heard)

> *Prov.* Children should not speak in the presence of adults. (Often used as a way to rebuke a child who has spoken when he or she should not.)
>
> *"You may come out and meet the party guests if you'll remember that children should be seen and not heard."*

This phrase is specifically targeted at children, and is somewhat dated today, but I believe it's the kind of thing you're looking for.

As I say, it's not really in common usage any more -- my grandparents definitely used to use it when I was young, if we got too noisy or asked too many questions, but I can't imagine many people using it on their kids today.

Comment: I hope my edit is to your liking, and if not, feel free to undo it. :)

Answer (score 4):

A couple spring to mind :-

> **An empty vessel makes the most noise**

Imagine a tin with a single pebble in it. If you shake it, it makes more noise than a tin packed with pebbles, or by implication someone with not much going on in their head, talks more than someone smarter.

The second one is from the North of England

> **If in doubt, say nowt!**

"nowt" is northern dialect for "nothing", pronounced "ow" as in "town".

Answer (score 3):

**"If you don't have anything nice to say, don't say anything."**

There are plenty of variations of this phrase:

"If you can't say something good about someone, sit right here by me." - [Alice Roosevelt Longworth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Alice_Roosevelt_Longworth)

"If you can't say something nice, don't say nothing at all." - [Thumper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumper_(Bambi))

Comment: Mama says plus one.

Comment: The question is about protecting oneself from negative ramifications of excessive honesty, not protecting other people's feelings.

Comment: @underscore_d You forgot to say something nice, and you know what they say about not having anything nice to say...

Comment: Hilarious. Sure, let's let off-topic answers proliferate because otherwise we might not be seen as everyone's friend. Have fun with that! These phrases have limited usefulness in certain contexts, but the overapplication is just plain dangerous IMO.

Comment: @underscore_d Yikes, I bet you're fun at parties. This answer isn't off topic. It might not be exactly what **you** would choose, but maybe **the next person with a similar but not exactly-the-same question** might find it useful. That's, uh, the entire point of this site. Btw I like your username!

Comment: @KevinWorkman That next person might, but I thought the point was to answer _this_ question, not some hypothetical future one. Well, anyway... skating past the jibe about parties, thanks for the compliment. I think it's a stupid name but not enough to pick another. And also, Game of Life ftw.

Comment: @underscore_d Maybe I'm just extending Stack Overflow's rule here, but you're definitely supposed to answer with **the next person with a similar question** in mind, not just the OP. That's one of the great things about this site- people with similar questions do a google search and come across these posts. There's even a "people reached" count in every person's profile, for keeping track of how many people you've helped. Your Stack Overflow profile says you've reached 23,000 people!

Comment: Wow, I should check that more often :-) All those poor people... haha. Fair enough. With any luck, you're right and other readers will find those phrases valuable. Thanks for humoring me!

Comment: Its vintage is quite recent, but I'd add [#ElonsLaw](https://twitter.com/hashtag/elonslawhttps://twitter.com/hashtag/elonslaw) from twitter: "You could just say nothing."

Answer (score 2):

There are two that I can think of.

> Shit rolls downhill.

Which means anger, blame, etc. come from those in power to those with little power.

> To learn the true source of power, find out who is not allowed to be criticized.

Which means the powerful person restricts criticism of themselves, or else those who do may no longer have a job or a life.

There are also two similar concepts that are related to what you are looking for:

Tall Poppy Syndrome: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_poppy_syndrome

> The tall poppy syndrome is a pejorative term primarily used in the United Kingdom, Australia, New Zealand, and other Anglosphere nations to describe a social phenomenon in which people of who have earned stature in the community are resented, attacked, cut down, or criticised because their talents or achievements elevate them above or distinguish them from their peers.

Crab Bucket Mentality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_mentality

> Crab mentality, sometimes referred to as crabs in a barrel. The metaphor refers to a bucket or barrel of crabs. Individually, the crabs could easily escape from the bucket, but instead they grab at each other in a useless "king of the hill" competition which prevents any from escaping and ensures their collective demise. The analogy in human behavior is claimed to be that members of a group will attempt to negate or diminish the importance of any member who achieves success beyond the others, out of envy, spite, conspiracy, or competitive feelings, to halt their progress.

Answer (score 0):

There are few Western proverbs that warn against “speaking up” in front of people because Western culture generally values initiative, speaking up and being a leader.

My favorite is "It's the pioneer that gets the arrows in the back" meaning the innovator takes the greatest risk.   However, the greatest risk has the greatest reward.

Comment: As a follow-up, albeit using a quite different analogy: "the second mouse gets the cheese" [from the trap sprung by the first mouse].

Answer (score 0):

**Better to remain silent and be thought a fool than to speak and remove all doubt.**

That and very similar phrases have been attributed to Abraham Lincoln, Mark Twain, the Bible, and other sources.