# More common terms for "tall poppy syndrome"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I came across this [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/04/07/fashion/what-is-anne-hathaway-doing-wrong.html):

> Ms. Hathaway could simply be a victim of what **the British call** “tall poppy syndrome” — the bloom that pokes above the others is the first to get cut.

I looked this term up and found this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_poppy_syndrome):

> ... In **Australia and New Zealand**, tall poppy syndrome refers to
> successful people being criticised...

There is some contradiction about where the term "tall poppy syndrome" comes from. but at least it seems that it is not a common term.

So is there a common term for this concept?

--- update ---

I am Chinese, in Chinese there are several similar sayings for this but before I knew "tall poppy syndrome", the closest saying I knew was "**The nail that sticks out gets hammered down**". So maybe my question should change to which one is more common *The nail that sticks out gets hammered down* or *tall poppy syndrome* ?

BTW, I used google bard to translate the three similar Chinese sayings into English, one is more refined, and the others are more appreciated by the masses. The following are its answers,

> In Chinese, there is a proverb that says, "枪打出头鸟." (the unrefined one)
> It means that those who stand out are often the ones who are targeted.
>
> The proverb "枪打出头鸟" is a reminder that those who are successful should
> be careful not to draw too much attention to themselves.
>
> 树大招风 (another unrefined one) is a Chinese proverb that literally means
> "a tall tree attracts the wind." It is often used to describe the
> phenomenon of people or things that stand out being more likely to be
> targeted for criticism, attack, or harm.
>
> In Chinese, there is a proverb that says, "木秀于林，风必摧之." (the refined
> one) It means that the tallest tree in the forest is the first to
> fall.
>
> The company's new CEO is a brilliant young woman. She is also very
> ambitious. Some people are concerned that she will be the victim of
> the "tall poppy syndrome.", as a proverb in Chinese says "木秀于林，风必摧之."
>
> In a society, a successful person is often attacked by jealous people.
> This can be explained by "The nail that sticks out gets hammered down"
> because the person's success makes the jealous people uncomfortable,
> so they use attacks to suppress him.
>
> In Australia, there is a phenomenon known as the "tall poppy
> syndrome." It means that people often criticize or suppress those who
> are successful or stand out.

My follow-up question is I guess this concept may not be common in English-speaking countries, especially in North America. Is that the case?

Comment: Is this the same question as [What is the word for a group holding back one of its members trying to rise above the group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/240027/191178)

Comment: [This "Children's Reader"](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_First_sixth_Reader_of_the_Popular_Se/QsZEAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22tall+poppy%22&pg=PA40&printsec=frontcover) from 1881 has a "tall Poppy" ***bragging*** to a lowly daisy about his impressive height (which he thinks everyone ***admires***). Before eventually repenting of his pride when it becomes apparent "the mowers" are coming, and the humble daisy will survive, but the haughty poppy will be cut down.

Comment: ...but [the more modern usage,](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/cut+down+the+tall+poppies.html) doesn't imply "arrogance" on the part of the successful people who've risen to the top. All that matters is they ***stand out from the crown*** - similar to [*put/stick/raise one's head above the parapet.*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%2Fstick%2Fraise%20one%27s%20head%20above%20the%20parapet)

Comment: There's a common term in Britain. Which variety of English are you interested in?

Comment: @FumbleFingers meant “stand out from the crow**d**.” And that sense of the tall-poppy expression makes it at least somewhat similar to *stick* [or *stand*] *out like a sore thumb*.

Comment: Possibly the idea may trace back to the Greek tyrant of Miletus, Thrasybulus in the 7th century BCE.  The 5th century historian, Herodotus in his 'History' records how the tyrant of Corinth sent a messenger to Thrasybulus paid a visit to Thrasybulus, seeking guidance on ruling.  Thrasybulus took the messenger for a walk in a field of wheat and, as he walked, cut off all the tallest ears.  Periander understood the message and used it to ruthless effect.  Sadly, 'Thrasybulian policy' would not catch on as an expression.

Comment: It's essentially the same sentiment as ***He whom the gods love dies young***, because *loved by the gods* is just a figurative way of saying *successful*, and having your figurative *flower* head cut off obviously means dying young (before you've *spread your seed / sown your wild oats* or *gone to seed* :)

Comment: There's a play on the original maxim: 'Success breeds envy.' It's reasonably common, but not a descriptive term for the situation as requested. // A trite saying from Marilyn Monroe: 'Success makes so many people hate you.'

Comment: For a literal treatment of tall poppies, see https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-65787391 showing Taliban clearance of opium poppy fields.  Apparently it is easy to lop off the capsules you can see just with a stick.

Comment: "That man is a head taller than me...that may change." -- Aguirre.

Comment: This covers the idea well, but I have no clue as to what may constitute a 'more common term'. It's common enough to not need an alternative. https://psychology-spot.com/tall-poppy-syndrome/

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments. I updated my question. Before I know "tall poppy syndrome." I only know "The nail that sticks out gets hammered down". That is why in my original question I asked "is there a common term for this concept?"

Comment: There's also a question about [alternatives to "the nail that sticks out gets hammered down"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/119705/191178)

Comment: I (in the US) know the term "tall poppy syndrome," but I always think of it as more of a British saying, which is why the *New York Times* was compelled to explain it.

Comment: I didn't know Japanese also has this concept ("the nail that pops up is always hammered down"). Thanks. But I guess this concept may not be common in English-speaking countries, especially in North America?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 I think the term "tall poppy syndrome" is quite commonly known in the UK, but not as common in the US.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the word for a group holding back one of its members trying to rise above the group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240027/what-is-the-word-for-a-group-holding-back-one-of-its-members-trying-to-rise-abov)

Comment: @livresque after reading all the answers there I feel that question is not exactly the same as mine. For example, I wasn't looking for a word/expression but asking if "tall poppy syndrome" is more common than "The nail that sticks out gets hammered down" (seems not) and if this concept is common in English-speaking countries, especially in NA (seem not again).